# VS2017 MSBuild autodetection takes MSBuild/v14 instead of v15 for WPF project

Tags: wpf, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

We are slowly migrating to VS2017 and most of the project do that silently without much interference. Today started migrating a WPF project from VS2015 to VS2017. When I build the solution I get the following warning:

```
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
```

I googled the problem but I seem to be alone out there. I have no clue what could cause this. The .Net target is 4.5.1 but changing that to 4.6.2 make no difference. Neither does clean or remove bin and obj directories. Who has got a clue?

Comment: What value have ToolsVersion property of your project?

Comment: Yep, that's probably it. It's 14.0.

Comment: Try change to 15.0.

Comment: I will. Currently repairing VS2017 :-(

Comment: Changed it to 15 but still get the warning

Comment: It seems to be nuget  is causing this:     
1>Task "Exec" (TaskId:20)
1>  Task Parameter:WorkingDirectory=bin\Debug\ (TaskId:20)
1>  Task Parameter:Command="C:\Projects\P2G\P2G\Sources\.nuget\nuget.exe" restore "C:\Projects\P2G\P2G\Sources\wur.p2g.sln" (TaskId:20)
1>  "C:\Projects\P2G\P2G\Sources\.nuget\nuget.exe" restore "C:\Projects\P2G\P2G\Sources\wur.p2g.sln" (TaskId:20)
1>  MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'. (TaskId:20)
1>  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed. (TaskId:20)

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this problem while building from the command line after migrating from VS2017 to VS2019 for a solution containing class libraries. I found I had VS2017's version of MSBuild in my PATH environment variable - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`. Removing that path from the environment variable and re-opening my console solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> VS2017 MSBuild autodetection takes MSBuild/v14 instead of v15 for WPF project

You can try to update the version of `nuget.exe` to the `4.0` and above in the `.nuget` folder.

Visual Studio 2017 comes with NuGet `4.0` and NuGet `4.0` Package Manager Extension is currently not available for Visual Studio 2015 (Visual Studio 2015 comes with NuGet `3.4.4`, and NuGet `3.5.0` is available as an explicit download for Visual Studio 2015 as well).

According to your comment, it seems the old nuget.exe not detect the MSBuild version `15.0`, so please try to update the nuget.exe to 4.0 and above in the `.nuget` folder.

Besides, I found your solution that is still configured by old package restore method "**MSBuild-integrated restore**", which is the original Package Restore implementation and though it continues to work in many scenarios, it does not cover the full set of scenarios addressed by the other two approaches.

[Automatic Package Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore) is the NuGet team's recommended approach to Package Restore within Visual Studio. You can convert to use the automatic package restore. Check the following thread for details:

[Nuget: Switching from "Enable Package Restore" to "Automatic Package Restore"](https://chrismay.org/2015/01/07/nuget-switching-from-enable-package-restore-to-automatic-package-restore/)

Hope this helps.